# GitHub CI - move a file using PHP copy() in a PHPUnit test

Tags: php, github

I have an application written in PHP 8. I've added some Unit Tests for it using [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/).

In one of the tests I am using PHP's [copy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function to move a file from one location to another. This is done to test an endpoint which downloads the file by moving a "dummy" file to the "real" location that the file would be in, in the production application.

My test looks like this:

```
// tests/TestCase/Controller/DocsControllerTest.php
public function testDownload()
{
    $testFile = '75e57e4a-2149-4270-9d76-c7c8f0298c2c.pdf';
    copy('/full/path/to/testFiles/' . $testFile, '/webroot/docs/');

    // Download the file from the endpoint
    $id = 9; // File ID to download
    $this->get('/download/' . $id); 
  
    // This should return a HTTP 200 response containing the PDF
    $this->assertResponseCode(200, 'Downloading a valid PDF should produce a 200 response.');
}
```

To explain the function above:

- We have a test file called `75e57e4a-2149-4270-9d76-c7c8f0298c2c.pdf`. This is a real PDF file with appropriate encoding.
- We move the file, using `copy()`, from a directory where we hold some test files, into the full directory path where the production web application will really store the files (`/webroot/docs/`).
- The remainder of the logic deals with downloading the file from the endpoint. The `$this->get` makes a HTTP GET request to an endpoint (`/download/`) which also passes in the appropriate file ID. The location of the file is looked up from a MySQL database and then is streamed to the browser, thus generating a HTTP 200 response containing the PDF.

This works both when I run phpunit locally by executing `vendor/bin/phpunit --filter testDownload`:

```
PHPUnit 9.5.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Time: 00:05.053, Memory: 20.00 MB
OK (1 test, 16 assertions)
```

It also works in a browser, i.e. if I make a request to `/download/9` I am served the appropriate PDF.

The problem I'm having is on GitHub. When I run the unit test there it fails the CI with this error:

```
Warning Error: copy(/home/runner/work/my-app/webroot/docs/75e57e4a-2149-4270-9d76-c7c8f0298c2c.pdf): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
In [/home/runner/work/my-app/tests/TestCase/Controller/DocsControllerTest.php, line 745]
```

Given that this works locally I can't understand why this error is occurring. Is there some restriction with using `copy()` in GitHub's CI?

The directory and files at `/full/path/to/testFiles/` are **not** `.gitignore`'d so they are committed with the rest of the repo code. So the test file, `75e57e4a-2149-4270-9d76-c7c8f0298c2c.pdf`, exists within the codebase on GitHub.

I am using PHPUnit 9.5.10, PHP 8.0 on a Mac running macOS Monterey (12.2).

Comment: Does the target folder exist?

Comment: @NicoHaase ah, you may well have answered this. The directory `/webroot/docs/` *is* `.gitignore`'d. That dir is the real location of the files in production. I guess I need a step in the CI to create this before running the tests?

Comment: Well, if that folder does not exist, you should create it. If it does exist, and the error is still thrown, please share some of your debugging attempts

Comment: Thanks Nico. I needed to create `webroot/docs/` within the test before attempting to use `copy()`.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly reads:

> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Maybe add `.gitkeep` into target directory `docs`? It may also be, that the source file is not there. One usually can take this error message literal. While it's entirely unclear what `$this->get()` even is or why your Mac would have anything to do with running GitHub Action?

Comment: It says in my question what `$this->get()` does - makes a HTTP GET request to the download endpoint, which is what I'm testing. My point was that it DOES work on my Mac but doesn't under GitHub's CI which is running the same tests. The reason it works locally has been answered by Nico; because locally I have the directory `/webroot/docs/` although this is not committed with the project code. I think I will modify the test to create it since committing that directory might lead to problems with deployment as it will eventually contain "real" files that shouldn't be in source control.

Comment: I don't care what you think the method does, unless reading the actual method. Why not simply assert that the source file exists and is readable, then assert that the target directory exists and is writable, then the result of the copy can merely be assumed as "done". `copy()` is for local file-system, not for URL.

Comment: I mean, where does the get GET request get the file from? Just try `service httpd status` ...the test suite should probably first assert, that it is possible to fetch anything from that (likely absent) HTTP server. The whole environment depends on the image used to instance the runner. The PHP internal web-server may be the only option, while not running an actual web-server - or requesting elsewhere.

Comment: Martin, the question has nothing to do with the `get()` method. The answer has already been given by Nico. It was that the destination directory (the second arg of `copy()`) didn't exist in the repo. So when it runs the tests it doesn't have anywhere to write the file to. I've modified the test to check the existence of the directory and create it if not. The app is written with CakePHP and the "GET" part uses https://api.cakephp.org/4.0/trait-Cake.TestSuite.IntegrationTestTrait.html#get(). It's now passing CI so there's no debate over whether a web server is or isn't present - it works.